# Configuring Internet facing deployment (IFD) for CRM 2013

Tags: crm, dynamics-crm-2013

What are the benefits and drawbacks of using IFD?

What are the steps for configuring IFD?

Is it possible to test configure IFD on Virtual Machine? If yes, please guide about the steps?
And if not? where to implement the procedure?

I have not implemented the CRM. and got assignment to implement IFD.

PS: I really want to implement all the things on my own. just need right way to do the things.

Thanks in advance for the Guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Interactive webs has a good description for ADFS/IFD on https://www.interactivewebs.com/blog/index.php/crm-2013/crm-2013-ifd-setup-with-adfs-3-0-on-windows-2012-r2-hosted-setup/ 
You can do the setup on a VM, make sure that the DNS is setup properly and it should work.

If you haven't worked with CRM at all it might be some bumps getting this working IMHO so it might take some time.

The pro of having an IFD CRM is that it's reachable from everywhere without having to use VPN, the drawback might be that it is no longer behind a firewall.